# Как в PyQt5 присоединить код с собственной функцией?

Tags: python, pyqt5

Делаю программу по переводу двоичный чисел в десятичные и обратно. Код по переводу десятичных в двоичные работает, а второй никак не могу присоединить в PyQt5. Алгоритм перевода двоичных в десятичные:

```
a=input("Введите двоичное целое число =")  
def underdef(digit):            
    length=len(digit)           
    helpdig=0           
    for i in range(0, length):               
        helpdig = helpdig+int(digit[i])*(2**(length-i-1))           
    return helpdig  
print("Двоичное целое число",a,"соответствует десятичному числу ", underdef(a))
```

Попытался присоединить его таким способом, где он под функцией `def binarik_2`:

```
import sys
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from binar import Ui_Dialog
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
ui = Ui_Dialog()
ui.setupUi(Dialog)
Dialog.show()

def binarik():
    num = int(ui.lineEdit.text())
    newNum = ''
    while num > 0:
        newNum = str(num % 2) + newNum
        num //= 2

    ui.label_4.setText(newNum)
ui.pushButton.clicked.connect( binarik )

def binarik_2():
    a = int(ui.lineEdit_2.text())
    def underdef(digit):
        length = len(digit)                   
        helpdig=0           
        for i in range(0, int(length)):               
            helpdig = helpdig+int(digit[i])*(2**(int(length)-i-1))           
        return helpdig   
    ui.label_3.setText(underdef(a))
ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect( binarik_2 )
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Содержание файла **binar.py**, из которого импортируется `Ui_Dialog`:

```
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(452, 360)
        Dialog.setStyleSheet("background-color:#e6fad2;\n"
"")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 70, 381, 31))
        self.lineEdit.setStyleSheet("color:#1db823;\n"
"font: 10pt \"Tw Cen MT Condensed Extra Bold\";\n"
"background-color:#0a2c40;\n"
"border:none;")
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 130, 111, 31))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("\n"
"QPushButton {\n"
"\n"
"    color:#f1f52a;\n"
"    font: 8pt \"MS Serif\";\n"
"    font: 11pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";\n"
"    background-color:#822af5;\n"
"    border:none;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color:silver;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"    background-color:red;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 240, 381, 31))
        self.lineEdit_2.setStyleSheet("color:#1db823;\n"
"font: 10pt \"Tw Cen MT Condensed Extra Bold\";\n"
"background-color:#0a2c40;\n"
"border:none;")
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 300, 111, 31))
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("\n"
"QPushButton {\n"
"\n"
"    color:#f1f52a;\n"
"    font: 8pt \"MS Serif\";\n"
"    font: 11pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";\n"
"    background-color:#822af5;\n"
"    border:none;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color:silver;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"    background-color:red;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 401, 31))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("font: 9pt \"MV Boli\";")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 190, 411, 31))
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("font: 9pt \"MV Boli\";")
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(156, 282, 291, 61))
        self.label_3.setText("")
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(156, 112, 291, 61))
        self.label_4.setText("")
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Dialog", "Dialog", None, -1))
        self.pushButton.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Dialog", "Преобразовать", None, -1))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Dialog", "Преобразовать", None, -1))
        self.label.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Dialog", "    Перевести из десятичной системы исчисления в двоичную:", None, -1))
        self.label_2.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Dialog", "    Перевести из двоичной системы исчисления в десятичную:", None, -1))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Юзер вводит число в lineEdit_2 и получает результат в Textlabel, который справа от кнопки.

[image]

На данный момент выводится такая ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\binar1.py", line 28, in binarik_2
    ui.label_3.setText(bin_to_dec(a))
  File "C:\Python\binar1.py", line 23, in bin_to_dec
    dlina=str(len(digit))
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

Помогите решить проблему.

Comment: Это "для себя" или задание? не понятно зачем городить велосипеды с переводом между системами счисления, если это "из коробки" умеет QString

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поменяйте имрорты и пробуйте:

```
import sys
#from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

#from binar import Ui_Dialog
class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(452, 360)
        Dialog.setStyleSheet("background-color:#e6fad2;\n"
"")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 70, 381, 31))
        self.lineEdit.setStyleSheet("color:#1db823;\n"
"font: 10pt \"Tw Cen MT Condensed Extra Bold\";\n"
"background-color:#0a2c40;\n"
"border:none;")
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 130, 111, 31))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("\n"
"QPushButton {\n"
"\n"
"    color:#f1f52a;\n"
"    font: 8pt \"MS Serif\";\n"
"    font: 11pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";\n"
"    background-color:#822af5;\n"
"    border:none;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color:silver;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"    background-color:red;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 240, 381, 31))
        self.lineEdit_2.setStyleSheet("color:#1db823;\n"
"font: 10pt \"Tw Cen MT Condensed Extra Bold\";\n"
"background-color:#0a2c40;\n"
"border:none;")
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 300, 111, 31))
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("\n"
"QPushButton {\n"
"\n"
"    color:#f1f52a;\n"
"    font: 8pt \"MS Serif\";\n"
"    font: 11pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";\n"
"    background-color:#822af5;\n"
"    border:none;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color:silver;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"    background-color:red;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 401, 31))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("font: 9pt \"MV Boli\";")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 190, 411, 31))
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("font: 9pt \"MV Boli\";")
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(156, 282, 291, 61))
        self.label_3.setText("")
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(156, 112, 291, 61))
        self.label_4.setText("")
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Dialog", "Dialog", None, -1))
        self.pushButton.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Dialog", "Преобразовать", None, -1))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Dialog", "Преобразовать2", None, -1))
        self.label.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Dialog", "    Перевести из десятичной системы исчисления в двоичную:", None, -1))
        self.label_2.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Dialog", "    Перевести из двоичной системы исчисления в десятичную:", None, -1))


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
ui = Ui_Dialog()
ui.setupUi(Dialog)
Dialog.show()

def binarik():
    num = int(ui.lineEdit.text())
    newNum = ''
    while num > 0:
        newNum = str(num % 2) + newNum
        num //= 2
    ui.label_4.setText(newNum)

ui.pushButton.clicked.connect( binarik )

def binarik_2():
#    a = int(ui.lineEdit_2.text())
    a = ui.lineEdit_2.text()

    def underdef(digit):
        length = len(digit)                   
        helpdig=0           
        for i in range(0, int(length)):               
            helpdig = helpdig+int(digit[i])*(2**(int(length)-i-1))           
        return helpdig  

#    ui.label_3.setText(underdef(a))
    ui.label_3.setText(str(underdef(a)))

ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect( binarik_2 )
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, мне надо код в binar1.py поменять на данный вами?

Comment: @ScriptK1ddy нет, вам надо поменять две строки. 1.`a = ui.lineEdit_2.text()`     2.`ui.label_3.setText(str(underdef(a)))`

Comment: Ещё раз спасибо за то, что снова выручили - всё работает. Остался один вопрос, как объединить всё это? У меня есть главное меню с кнопками, при нажатии на которые открывались бы мои формы. Задам еще один вопрос и буду очень признателен, если вновь поможете.

Comment: @ScriptK1ddy если мой ответ решил вашу проблему, не забудьте отметить его как правильный.